# How to use AND operator and NOT operator in Regular Expressions .Net

Tags: c#, regex

I need to accept the values if it is `foo 100.00` . In this foo will be constant and the number can vary.

I need to avoid if zeros are entered in place of 100.00: say ex : `foo 0.00` .

1. I found the Regex for foo 100.00 as : `^foo[\s]*[\d{1,}+(\.\d{1,2})?]`
2. and the regex for finding foo 0.00 as :  `^foo[\s]*([0]{0,}(\.[0]{0,})?)*$`

Now i need to check whether the input data matches the 1) and it should not match 2).

```
scenario 1 : foo 100 - pass 
scenario 2 : foo 0.00 - fail 
scenario 3 : foo 123 - pass
Scenario 4 : foo 0.23 - pass
```

How can I do this . I tried a lot of lookaround type of solutions. Nothing gives a proper result. I need to do this with regex because my C# code has an matching algorithm that matches only one regex at a time and it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one does the job:

```
^foo\s+(?!0\.00$)\d+\.\d+$
```

Where `(?!0\.00$)` is a negative lookahead that makes sure there is no `0.00`

If the decimal part is optional:

```
^foo\s+(?!0\.00$)\d+(?:\.\d+)$
```

To reject `0` and `0.0`  and `0.00`:

```
^foo\s+(?!0(?:\.00?)?$)\d+(?:\.\d+)$
```

Comment: It is not passing - foo 123 , because it does not contain 0.00 in it :|

Comment: @VidiyaPrasanth: See my edit to deal with optional decimal part.

Comment: i tweaked yours a lil bit : ^foo\s+(?!0.0$)\d+(?:\.\d*)*$   and i am almost cool with all values except foo 0.0 and foo 0 .  Can you help me with that plzzzzz . Thanks for your great work